# How to retrieve only <entry key> from whatever BibLatex reference

Tags: biblatex

I'm building a bibliographic index card, like the ones used in old libraries. So, I have a "bib" file with only one entry (because I'll print one at a time - this will be my reading list). I have made everything. But I need to retrieve the BibTex `<entry key>`, whatever it is (book, thesis, whatever). My aim is to use this  to automatically generate a barcode at the top of my index card. Cool humm. ;)

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to read this `<entry key>` and put it in a string variable, using `\def\mystring{<entry key here>}`.

This is my index card now:

[image]

[Question solved here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/582289/35864)

Comment: It would help *a lot* if you could share (a reduced version of) the code you used to produce the output you are showing. Then we could experiment with our suggestions and see directly if it works in your application. (Sometimes not all solutions work for all applications.)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly what you mean by `entry key`. Usually in `biblatex` speak the entry key is internal 'name'/identifier of the bibliography entry (which you can use to cite the entry), e.g. in `@book{worman, author = {Worman, Nancy}, title = {The Cast of Character}, date = 2002, publisher = {University of Texas Press}, location = {Austin},}` the entry key is `worman`. The fact that the question mentions (book, thesis, whatever) makes me suspect you might be looking for the *entry type* (in `biblatex` speak), which would be `@book` in this example.

Comment: Hi @moewe you can have access to the code her: https://www.overleaf.com/4813568249drmwkbfjsqkr

Comment: Hi @moewe what I mean with the <entry code> (using your example) is "worman".

Comment: I guess this question here is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/582289/35864 now?

Answer (score 0):

The you print a `biblatex` field using the `\citefield` command. The command takes two arguments, the first is the actual `<entry-key>` and the second is the field, in this case `entrykey`.  Thus you have to use

```
\citefield{<entry-key>}{entrykey}.
```

However, this beg the question, why not using the `<entry-key>` directly?

Comment: Hi @Guido  I put the complete code I'm using here: https://www.overleaf.com/4813568249drmwkbfjsqkr so you can take a look, if you wnat and understand better what I'm trying to do.